# [HttpRequestException]: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

Actually when i try to run my application from my localhost, its working fine. After i published my application into server,its working fine in Firefox. But when i tried to run using Chrome, its not working.

**Error Message:**

```
[HttpRequestException]: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 
(Internal Server Error).
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
at SystemMVC_Version2._0.Controllers.ClaimsController.ClaimRecord(String Bill_no, 
   String Bill_date, String VisitDate, String ActualAmount, Double CoPay, Double ClaimAmount, 
   String Cv_Id, String TotalClaimAmount, String Consult_Type, String MemberIDNo, 
   String MCType, String StartDate, String EndDate, String McRemark, String Diagnosis, 
   String DoctorNames, String Medication, String MedicationQty, String MedicationUnitPrice, 
   String MedicationCost, String AdditionalMedicineCode, String AdditionalMedicineQty, 
   String AdditionalMedicationUnitPrice, String AdditionalMedicationCost, String ProcID, 
   String ProcedureCost, String PreferedMedicationSelected, String DocID, String LockAmount, 
   String IsMC, String IsClaim, String IsDepartment, String IsEmployee, String IsDependent, 
   String PatientName, String IsCorp, String Department, String EmailNotDepartment, 
   String MembrType)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

**My Ajax Call**

```
 $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#submit-button").prop('disabled', true); // disable button
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("ClaimRecord", "Claims")',
        data: JSON.stringify({
                                Bill_no: b_no, Bill_date: b_date, VisitDate: pv_date, ActualAmount: ActAmt, CoPay: CpayAmt, ClaimAmount: ClaimAmt,
                                Cv_Id: cv_id, TotalClaimAmount: TotalClaimAmnt, Consult_Type: Type, MemberIDNo: MemId, MCType: resType,
                                StartDate: datefrom, EndDate: dateend, McRemark: remark, Diagnosis: selectedValues, DoctorNames: Doctor,
                                Medication: Medcode, MedicationQty: MedQty, MedicationUnitPrice: MedUnitPrice, MedicationCost: Cost,
                                AdditionalMedicineCode: MedcodeExtra, AdditionalMedicineQty: MedQtyExtra, AdditionalMedicationUnitPrice: MedUnitPriceExtra,
                                AdditionalMedicationCost: CostExtra, ProcID: Procedureid, ProcedureCost: ProcCost, PreferedMedicationSelected: preferdMed,
                                DocID: drid, LockAmount: Lckamt, IsMC: mc, IsClaim: clm, IsDepartment: isdept, IsEmployee: isemp, IsDependent: isdepen,
                                PatientName: pname, IsCorp: iscorp,Department: dept, EmailNotDepartment: endept, MembrType: mtype
        }),

        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',

        success: function (response) {
            window.location.href = response.redirectTo;
            alert("This Claim submitted Successfully. Claim ReferenceNo is :" + ' ' + response.par);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Not Successfull" + jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
  public ActionResult ClaimRecord(string Bill_no, string Bill_date, string VisitDate, string ActualAmount, string CoPay, string ClaimAmount,
                                    string Cv_Id, string TotalClaimAmount, string Consult_Type,  string MemberIDNo, string MCType,
                                    string StartDate, string EndDate, string McRemark, string Diagnosis, string DoctorNames,string Medication,
                                    string MedicationQty, string MedicationUnitPrice, string MedicationCost, string AdditionalMedicineCode,
                                    string AdditionalMedicineQty, string AdditionalMedicationUnitPrice, string AdditionalMedicationCost,
                                    string ProcID, string ProcedureCost, string PreferedMedicationSelected, string DocID, string LockAmount,
                                    string IsMC, string IsClaim, string IsDepartment, string IsEmployee, string IsDependent, string PatientName, string IsCorp,
                                    string Department, string EmailNotDepartment, string MembrType)
    {
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            string url = "http://ipaddress/SystemAPI/";
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            ClaimTxn ct = new ClaimTxn()
                {
                    CreateUserID = UserId,
                    CreateDate = CreateDate,
                    ModifyUserID = UserId,
                    ModifyDate = CreateDate,
                    ClaimDate = CreateDate,
                    ClaimSubmitDate = CreateDate,
                    BillNo = Bill_no,
                    BillDate = Bill_date,
                    TreatmentStartDate = VisitDate,
                    TreatmentEndDate = VisitDate,
                    MemberID = MemberIDNo,
                    ProviderID = PID,
                    ProviderName = ProviderName,
                    Amount = ActualAmount,
                    Copay = CoPay,
                    McType = MCType,
                    McStartDate = StartDate,
                    McDays = Days,
                    ClaimAmount = TotalClaimAmount,
                    ConfirmVisitID = Cv_Id,
                    ConsultationType = Consult_Types
                };

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<ClaimTxn>("api/ClaimSubmisstion/InsertintoClaimTxn", ct).Result;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
  }
```

so, when i run the application from localhost, there is no issues. The response code is 201. But when i try to run from server using chrome, I am getting status code 500. So how can i fix this issues.
Any help appriciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: So it seems the ClaimRecord itself os throwing that error? Are you passing exactly the same data in on live as production - i.e. the same integration test?

Comment: Yes, I passed the same data

Comment: I presume the error above is from `HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<ClaimTxn>("api/ClaimSubmisstion/InsertintoClaimTxn", ct).Result;`?

Comment: Yeah. But its working from localhost @garfbradaz

Comment: Did you ever find a solution I am having the same issue